# How to suppress Nuitka logs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nuitka

When I execute Nuitka, there're always some logs and warning showing up. How do I suppress this?
Example: `python3 -m nuitka --follow-imports --standalone --remove-output main.py`

Answer (score 1):

Append `2 > /dev/null` to the command. This redirects stderr output to `/dev/null` which throws it away.